# Facebook graph api get the user's infomation

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a website which users can see their posted pictures on the page.

I have signed up for facebook API and have an app id and app secret.

[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={#}&client_secret={#}&grant_type=client_credentials](http://%20https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%7B#%7D&client_secret=%7B#%7D&grant_type=client_credentials)

I send users to the oauth to get the user's access token but I don't know what to do next.

[https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,name,posts&access_token={#}](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,name,posts&access_token=%7B#%7D)

I thought this would work but I had the error below
"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",

Comment: _“I send users to the oauth”_ - show us where/how you did that then.

Comment: I thought https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={#}&client_secret={#}&grant_type=client_credentials returns a json formatted access token

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using to get the Access Token is actually an App Token API.
To generate the Access Token Please replace

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={#}&client_secret={#}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

with

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&client_id={#id}&redirect_uri={#}&scope=publish_pages
```

add a redirection url here where the token is published.

OR

better option is to use the login button mentioned here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

Also you can read here about all Access Tokens

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/